# Flutter Local Notification Weekly Repeat Notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, android-notifications, local

can anyone help me to figure it out, I am trying to integrate Flutter Local Notification to my small project, Dynamically I am adding  time and day not date, and want to repeat the notification on selected time and day weekly(Let's say I am selecting Saturday 10.30 PM and want to repeat the notification on every week same time & same day), it's not working, am I doing something wrong? earlier api of "flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showWeeklyAtDayAndTime" was easy to undersatnd but it's deprecated. Note: "newDay " user selected day of a week, "time.hour & time.minute" is user selected time

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        "Hurry! It's Working time!",
        'Get Ready for Workout!',
        _nextInstanceOfWeeklySchedule(),
        // tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(diff),
        const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'weekly notification channel id',
            'weekly notification channel name',
            'weekly notificationdescription',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            enableLights: true,
          ),
        ),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime);
  }
tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfWeeklySchedule() {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month,
        newDay, time.hour, time.minute - 5, now.second);
    print(scheduledDate);
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(minutes: 1));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't worry answer is here :

function to schedule weekly notification at selected date and time and day of week -

[Click here to see code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gggPU.png)

Then you can call weekScheduleFun(_selectedDate ,10,3) to schedule notification .

_selectedDate : DateTime variable,
10- hour ,
3 -minutes .